# get name of a function that is passed as argument to nested functions in R

Tags: r

In R, I need the name of a function that was passed as argument to nested functions.

```
> fun1 <- function(f) deparse(substitute(f))
> fun2 <- function(f) fun1(f)
> fun1(mean)
[1] "mean"
> fun2(mean)
[1] "f"
>
```

How can I obtain the name of a function independent of the number of times it has been passed as an argument to nested functions?

Comment: Not all functions have names. What would `fun1(function(x) x)` return? It would probably be better to say what you hope to accomplish at a larger scale rather than this particular technical detail. There are probably better ways to do things safely and reliably in R.

Answer (score 5):

This does the substitution in the first frame on the stack:

```
fun1 <- function(f) deparse(substitute(f, sys.frame(1)))

fun2 <- function(f) fun1(f)

fun1(mean)
#[1] "mean"
fun2(mean)
#[1] "mean"
```

Obviously, this will fail if you don't pass the argument through from the most outer function:

```
fun3 <- function() fun2(mean)
fun3()
#[1] "f"
```

If will also fail, if you change the parameter name:

```
fun2 <- function(g) fun1(g)
fun2(mean)
#[1] "f"
```

However, it might be sufficient for your use case (which you haven't described).

If those constraints are a problem, we need something more sophisticated and inefficient:

```
fun1 <- function(f) {

  fr <- rev(sys.frames())

  f <- substitute(f, fr[[1]])

  #loop over the frame stack
  for (i in seq_along(fr)[-1]) {
    f <- eval(bquote(substitute(.(f), fr[[i]])))
  }

  deparse(f)
}

fun2 <- function(g) fun1(g)

fun3 <- function() fun2(mean)

fun1(mean)
#[1] "mean"
fun2(mean)
#[1] "mean"
fun3()
#[1] "mean"
```

Of course, this would still break in edge cases:

```
fun4 <- function(mean) fun3()
fun4(2)
#[1] "2"
```

You could try handling them, but I'll stop here.